# Modifying highlight color of identify but from the startup file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, color

I want to do it in programming, I use PyQGIS.
I was researching what the class uses

```py
qgis.gui.QgsHighlight (mapCanvas:QgsMapCanvas, geom:QgsGeometry, layer:QgsMapLayer)
```

But I would like to do this from the startup configuration file, the only thing I want is to change the color (setColor).

But I have not been able to instantiate the class only using the canvas.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to put the following in the `startup.py` file

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings

settings = QSettings()
settings.setValue("Map/highlight/color", '#ff6500')
```

I'm not sure you can get what you want using `QgsHighlight`. It accepts 3 parameters. Amongst them, I don't see how you could set a reference to a `QgsGeometry` or a particular `QgsMapLayer` when starting